# R: Turning row data from one dataframe into column data by group in another

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, simplify

I have data in the following format:

| ID | Age | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | M |
| 2 | 32 | F |
| 3 | 18 | F |
| 4 | 89 | M |
| 5 | 45 | M |

and;

| ID | subID | Type | Status | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Car | Y |  |
| 1 | 11 | Toyota | NULL | 2011 |
| 1 | 23 | Kia | NULL | 2009 |
| 2 | 5 | Car | N |  |
| 3 | 2 | Car | Y |  |
| 3 | 4 | Honda | NULL | 2019 |
| 3 | 7 | Fiat | NULL | 2006 |
| 3 | 8 | Mitsubishi | NULL | 2020 |
| 4 | 1 | Car | N |  |
| 5 | 7 | Car | Y |  |

Each ID in the second table has a row specifying if they have a car, and additional rows stating the brand of car/s they own. Each person has a maximum of 3 cars. I want to simplify this data into a single table as so.

| ID | Age | Sex | Car? | Car.1 | Car1.year | Car.2 | Car2.year | Car.3 | Car3.year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | M | Y | Toyota | 2011 | Kia | 2009 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 32 | F | N | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 18 | F | Y | Honda | 2019 | Fiat | 2006 | Mitsubishi | 2020 |
| 4 | 89 | M | N | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 45 | M | Y | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I've tried using the mutate function in dplyr with the case_when function, but I can't check conditions in another dataframe. If I try to join the tables together, I would have multiple rows for each ID which I want to avoid. The non-standard set up of the second table makes things complicated. My only remaining idea is to switch to Python/Pandas and create a for loop that slowly loops through each ID, searches the second dataframe if the person has a car and the car brands, then mutates a column in the first dataframe. But given the size of my dataset, this would be inefficient and take a long time.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What coding problems do you have?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  In the tidyverse ecosystem you can use the pivot_wider and inner_join functions to get you there.  `pivot_wider()` can turn the multiple records per person into a single wide record.  `inner_join()` can then merge them into a single dataset.  You can use the dput() function to make text version of your tables and somebody can write the solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following codes:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID   Age Sex  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    29 M    
2     2    32 F    
3     3    18 F    
4     4    89 M    
5     5    45 M  

df2

# A tibble: 10 x 5
      ID subID Type       Status  Year
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1     3 Car        Y         NA
 2     1    11 Toyota     Y       2011
 3     1    23 Kia        Y       2009
 4     2     5 Car        N         NA
 5     3     2 Car        Y         NA
 6     3     4 Honda      Y       2019
 7     3     7 Fiat       Y       2006
 8     3     8 Mitsubishi Y       2020
 9     4     1 Clothed    N         NA
10     5     7 Clothed    Y         NA


df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Status = if_else(Status == "NULL", "Y", Status))
df3 <- df2 %>% filter(!is.na(Year)) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(index = row_number())  
df4 <- df3  %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID), values_from = c(Type, Year), names_from = index )
```

So your desired output will be produced:

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% select(ID, Status) %>% distinct()) %>% left_join(df4) 

# A tibble: 5 x 10
     ID   Age Sex   Status Type_1 Type_2 Type_3     Year_1 Year_2 Year_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    29 M     Y      Toyota Kia    NA           2011   2009     NA
2     2    32 F     N      NA     NA     NA             NA     NA     NA
3     3    18 F     Y      Honda  Fiat   Mitsubishi   2019   2006   2020
4     4    89 M     N      NA     NA     NA             NA     NA     NA
5     5    45 M     Y      NA     NA     NA             NA     NA     NA
```